# Error while launching appium inspector with ipa package on mac

Tags: ios, macos, appium, inspector

I am using Appium inspector in Mac Os to inspect an elements on iOS app.

```
http://appium.io/
```

When I launch Appium inspector with ios package details, I am unable to launch ios app using appium and getting the below error as follows:-

Used tools version are listed below:-

```
Appium version:- 1.3.7
Xcode version:- 6.1.1
Mac os: 10.10.2
```

Error log:-

```
Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --pre-launch --log "/tmp/appium.log" --platform-version "8.1" --platform-name "iOS" --app "com.vervewireless.iphone.qa.beta" --show-ios-log --device-name "iPhone 6"

info: [debug] Starting Appium in pre-launch mode

info: Pre-launching app

info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing

info: [debug] Creating new appium session 62b3e6af-2864-4256-9559-97b5a17fcb44

info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets

info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder

info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout

info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.1

info: [debug] Checking whether instruments supports our device string

info: [debug] Getting list of devices instruments supports

info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments

info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 6","platformVersion":"8.1"}

info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)'

info: [debug] iOS sim UDID is 4391D23F-BA21-4FB8-8887-0972D2911420
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate

info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim

info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.vervewireless.iphone.qa.beta/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.vervewireless.iphone.qa.beta/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn't exist
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/alkaffkhan/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap

info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"oneByOne"}
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
...
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/alkaffkhan/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-931e8d7703a594e3.js

error: Could not set the device type in Info.plist

info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/alkaffkhan/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-931e8d7703a594e3.js
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 6","platformVersion":"8.1"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)'
info: [debug] We're on iOS7.1+ so forcing defaultDevice on
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 6","platformVersion":"8.1"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)'
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.vervewireless.iphone.qa.beta/Info.plist
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.vervewireless.iphone.qa.beta/Info.plist
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --pre-launch --log "/tmp/appium.log" --platform-version "8.1" --platform-name "iOS" --app "com.vervewireless.iphone.qa.beta" --show-ios-log --device-name "iPhone 6"

info: [debug] Starting Appium in pre-launch mode

info: Pre-launching app

info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 255637cf-2d12-41c3-8610-e53f804d229b
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder

info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout

info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.1
info: [debug] Checking whether instruments supports our device string
info: [debug] Getting list of devices instruments supports
info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments

info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 6","platformVersion":"8.1"}

info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator)'
info: [debug] iOS sim UDID is 4391D23F-BA21-4FB8-8887-0972D2911420

info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.vervewireless.iphone.qa.beta/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/com.vervewireless.iphone.qa.beta/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn't exist
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/alkaffkhan/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"oneByOne"}
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!
...

error: Could not set the device type in Info.plist
```

Comment: Is the same issue happening with .app file for iOS for automation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the appium.app. I had this issue before and disabling the BundleID bypassed this error message for me.

Also, make sure that the device you are selecting does not have the UDID included. You can delete the UDID after you select the device in the dropdown.

Try running the inspector with only App Path and Force Device checkboxes enabled.